# Theme doesn't change correctly in maui for elements with no background when the system theme is black

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, app-themes

When changing the theme of the OS, the application normally does not display all entries. I tried to change the background of the entry, but then the frames are not visible on iOS, and if it is empty (without a placeholder), then it will be extremely difficult to find it.
Added `Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light` to the `App.xaml.cs` file.

[image: Screenshot.]

The problem is present on both iOS and Android.

Comment: Please see [ask] and read SO's [tour].

Comment: Maui relies on native platform controls. Each platform might have different defaults for background colors. This is easily fixed by defining a `Style` for each element type that you use. In that style, set an appropriate background color. Then you need to know how to have style adapt to different theme. Search for Xamarin.Forms questions that show this - not sure if there is Maui example yet.

Comment: I've also experienced this already before, this might actually be a bug in MAUI. Have you checked the issues of the MAUI GitHub repository?

Comment: Yes, this is most likely a MAUI and .NET 7 issue @ewerspej

Perhaps this is related to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13627#issue-1605749809

Comment: That  may also related to this issue [App.Current.RequestedThemeChanged doesn't fire](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10310)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem is that I use a custom entry in which I do not specify a background color, after setting it to Transparent, the entry is displayed normally, except that there is no frame around (ios) and underlining (android). So far I just wrapped the record in a `border` and it works.

I'll leave the question open for now, maybe someone will find a more elegant solution to the problem

**Update:**
I stumbled upon this article and after trying this method, I no longer met the dark theme https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/231994/disable-dark-mode-in-xamarin-forms-4-8

Comment: what about the other controls, they also have same issue like date picker?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to respond to system theme change is use **AppThemeBinding markup extension**.

```
<Entry BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Green, Dark=Yellow}"/>
```

or you may use Style:

```
<Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="EntryStyle">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
            Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightNavigationBarColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkNavigationBarColor}}" />
</Style>
```

For more info, you could refer to [Respond to system theme changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: The way I understand the problem, the OP is already doing that. I've experienced the same problems with Entries, there might still be a bug in MAUI.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Maybe I misunderstood this question. Do you mean entry property not respond to system theme change?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand the question and that's also what I'm experiencing myself.